# Grey score since a few days

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, design, top-bar

Since a few days my score has become grey (picture below). It has always been white. Is it just the website that has changed? Has anybody had the same 'problem'?

[image]

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness). (It wasn't really white, just a much lighter gray.)